# Scrape tag value

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i want to ask that can i scrape value of a tag with beautifulsoup:
i want to get an img src:

```
<img class="product-pic" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1385/4109/products/Beef_Patties_grande_41a52a6f-1d85-499c-be1d-06ecb318c2ad_large.jpg?v=1469212539" alt="Beef Burgers">
```

i want to scrape value of src. i.e.

```
//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1385/4109/products/Beef_Patties_grande_41a52a6f-1d85-499c-be1d-06ecb318c2ad_large.jpg?v=1469212539
```

what i'm doing is:

```
containers[0].find("img").next_element.next_element.next_element.next_element.next_element.next_element
```

but i'm not getting the expected output, what i'm getting is:

```
<a href="/collections/beef/products/beef-burgers">Beef Burgers</a>
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: What do you get if you try like `soup.select_one("img[class='product-pic']")['src']`?

Comment: @SIM thanks for your reponse, i got my answer and i have posted it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to my question, all i have to do is simple:

```
img = containers[0].find("img",{"class":"product-pic"})
src = img["src"]
```

output:

```
'//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1385/4109/products/Beef_Patties_grande_41a52a6f-1d85-499c-be1d-06ecb318c2ad_large.jpg?v=1469212539'
```